# Error after installation Tensorflow keras with gpu on ubuntu 18.04: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/share/jupyter/nbconvert/templates/conf.json'

Tags: jupyter-notebook, tf.keras

Showing PermissionError after installation like:

> [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/share/jupyter/nbconvert/templates/conf.json

when I am opening a new Jupyter notebook. Please reply how to overcome this error.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the path `/usr/share/` (the path to Jupyter directory showing in the error where `nbconvert` is under that) and remove the `Jupyter` directory by typing `rm -rf Jupyter` and run the notebook again.